# How can I make a specific calculation out of a JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

Below you can find a json file. This file is containing results from a speech.

**Current Situation:**

You can see the "CombinedResults" containing all the text. In my example:

> hey good morning this is X from am i'm working as a employee and this
>   is just an audio file to test"

**Desired Situation**

Instead of only the whole text, I want to see the silence in seconds in a conversation as well.

> hey good morning **[seconds: 3.1]** this is X from am i'm working as a employee and this
>   is just an audio file to test"

**How can I solve this?**

There is a possibility to get the desired output. What I think that I need to do:

1. Loop through the "SegmentResults" and save the 
   A). "OffsetInSeconds",
   B)."DurationInSeconds",
   C). "NBest" -> "Lexical" (containing the text).
2. After that, this calculation can help us with the 'seconds' calculation:

> ('OffsetInSeconds' + 'DurationInSeconds') of the previous
>   'SegmentResult'
>    -  ('OffsetInSeconds') of the current 'SegmentResult'

In this example: difference between 0.57 + 1.67 = 2.24 & 5.34  = 3.1 seconds.

I tried to code this, but I am some kind of stuck. Why? Because I can calculate the 'OffsetInSeconds' + 'DurationInSeconds' for the current Segment (where I am looping in now). However, I miss the previous calculation then. Also getting all the text in the desired output is an issue.

Hopefully someone can help. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
# Focus on the SegmentResults 
All_result_list = Test_JSON["AudioFileResults"][0].get("SegmentResults") 

# Loop over the SegmentResults, to get each Segment separately 

for speech_result in All_result_list:
    print(type(speech_result))
    #print(speech_result)
    Pause_Time = 0 
    Off_Set_Seconds = speech_result.get('OffsetInSeconds')
    Duration_Seconds = speech_result.get('DurationInSeconds')

    print(Off_Set_Seconds)
    print(Duration_Seconds)
    Text_All = speech_result.get('NBest')

    for correct_text in Text_All:
        Text = correct_text.get('Lexical')
        print(Text)
```

Please find here the json file:

```
Test_JSON = {
  "AudioFileResults": [
    {
      "AudioFileName": "Channel.0.wav",
      "AudioFileUrl": null,
      "AudioLengthInSeconds": 29.76,
      "CombinedResults": [
        {
          "ChannelNumber": null,
          "Lexical": "hey good morning this is X from am i'm working as a employee and this is just an audio file to test",
          "ITN": "hey good morning this is X from am i'm working as a employee and this is just an audio file to test",
          "MaskedITN": "Hey good morning This is X from am I'm working as a employee and this is just an audio file to test",
          "Display": "Hey good morning. This is X from am I'm working as a employee and this is just an audio file to test"
        }
        ],
      "SegmentResults": [
        {
          "RecognitionStatus": "Success",
          "ChannelNumber": null,
          "SpeakerId": null,
          "Offset": 5700000,
          "Duration": 16700000,
          "OffsetInSeconds": 0.57,
          "DurationInSeconds": 1.67,
          "NBest": [
            {
              "Confidence": 0.9073331,
              "Lexical": "hey good morning",
              "ITN": "hey good morning",
              "MaskedITN": "Hey good morning",
              "Display": "Hey good morning.",
              "Sentiment": null,
              "Words": null
            }
            ]
        },
        {
          "RecognitionStatus": "Success",
          "ChannelNumber": null,
          "SpeakerId": null,
          "Offset": 53400000,
          "Duration": 66700000,
          "OffsetInSeconds": 5.34,
          "DurationInSeconds": 6.67,
          "NBest": [
            {
              "Confidence": 0.8709568,
              "Lexical": "this is X from am i'm working as a employee and this is just an audio file to test",
              "ITN": "this is X from am i'm working as a employee and this is just an audio file to test",
              "MaskedITN": "This is X from am I'm working as a employee and this is just an audio file to test",
              "Display": "This is X from am I'm working as a employee and this is just an audio file to test.",
              "Sentiment": null,
              "Words": null
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just need to track the previous value of offset in seconds + duration in seconds.

```py
previous_time = None

for speech_result in All_result_list:
    print(type(speech_result))

    Off_Set_Seconds = speech_result.get('OffsetInSeconds')
    Duration_Seconds = speech_result.get('DurationInSeconds')

    if previous_time:
        Pause_Time = Off_Set_Seconds - previous_time
        print(f'[seconds: {Pause_Time}]')

    previous_time = Off_Set_Seconds + Duration_Seconds

    Text_All = speech_result.get('NBest')
```

Maybe this is a spacing issue, but why are you nesting the loop here? It looks like there is only one item in the list in your JSON example. If so, just call the [0] element.

```py
    for correct_text in Text_All:
        Text = correct_text.get('Lexical')
        print(Text)
```

Comment: The nesting the loop part is done because many items inside the 'NBest' are representing the same stuff (for example 'ITN', 'MaskedITN', 'Display' etc). Therefore, I focused on only 1 of them ('Lexical').

Comment: Your solution works for all the pauses, except for the first pause that occurs

Comment: How should the first pause look? It is an opening pause before the speaker starts to talk?  I asked about the second loop, because it looks like using the get method on NBest for 'lexical' should only return the lexical item, without the need for the loop.

Comment: As I think about it a bit more, probably just leave the second for loop in, ignore my previous thoughts on it.